# How to find custom logos from an image using nodejs

Tags: node.js, opencv, image-processing, nodejs-server

I am trying to find logo exists in an image or not, where i have create some logos list in png format.

I have tried using opencv with nodejs.
I have used OPENCV image-templating but I am not getting actual solutions.

Example:
I have some list of logos.
I have captured an image.
Not i have to detected in the image there is any logo exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried training an ai to look at the logos you want to find or image recognition?

Comment: No i don’t have idea. But i can try using this idea. Thanks.